# Meteor Easy-Search including two field names into autosuggest box

Tags: meteor, meteor-easy-search

So I have an [easy-search](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/getting-started/) template as such:

```
{{> EasySearch.Autosuggest index=PlayersIndex labelField="Player" valueField="Team"}}
```

My index is defined as:

```
export const PlayersIndex = new Index({
  collection: Stocks,
  fields: ['Player', 'Team'],
  engine: new MinimongoEngine(),
});
```

And I want the autosuggest box to display both the Player and the Team. Right now it just shows the Player. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should first visit [the autosuggest's documentation](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/tree/master/packages/easysearch:autosuggest) which is pretty short. From there it's pretty clear that only the first member of the fields array (in your case "Player") is chosen as the value to present when searching. To change this behavior you can pass a different template through the `renderSuggestion` parameter that `EasySearch.Autosuggest` seems to accept. By default it's using the 
`EasySearch_Autosuggest_DefaultRenderSuggestion` template which you can find [here](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/blob/master/packages/easysearch:autosuggest/lib/autosuggest.html). You can just create your own template in one of your files

```
<template name="playerTeamAuto">
  <div>
    <span class="autosuggest-title">
      <span class="name">{{label}}</span>
      &nbsp;
      <span class="teamName">{{doc.Team}}</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

This will work only for your set of results where the returned documents would have a guranteed field of `Team` that's why we can access it through the `doc` variable. This comes from the object that the template is rendered with [here on this specific line.](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/blob/master/packages/easysearch:autosuggest/lib/autosuggest.js#L49) As you can see it has all the data fields returned through the form of `item`, as even the `label` is gotten from there. I've added a `&nbsp;` between the player and team name, but you can format them any way you want.